# Files missing in publish folder for angular 2 .net core project

Tags: angular, .net-core

I am using the template for angular 2 in net core as shown here http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/ . When I publish the solution, the files inside the "app" inside ClientApp folder is completely missing. I have all the angular components inside this folder and it's not getting published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to include my client scripts is I added this line to my .csproj file under other `<Content>` lines:

```
<Content Include="Client\dist\**\*.*" />
```

Answer (score 2):

[The files section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#files) in the `project.json` vs `csproj` documentation explains the solution.

If you are using `project.json`

```
{
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "app/"
    ]
  }
}
```

If you are using `csproj`

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="app\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: @Maverik You're using project.json... is that right?

Comment: yes. I am using the .net core template for angular2; which comes with project.json